# Error on cursor when selecting from database SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

When I'm trying to get the info from my database into a table, I'm getting this error:

```
05-15 14:15:55.250: E/AndroidRuntime(28050): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Sofia.MemoryGame/com.Sofia.MemoryGame.SQLView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: KEY_ROWID: , while compiling: SELECT KEY_ROWID, KEY_Name, KEY_Score FROM ScoreList
```

Here is my code:

```
    public String getData() {

    Cursor c = myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABEL, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_Name, KEY_Score}, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Name);
    int iScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Score);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScore) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I´m getting the error on the Cursor. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here i also the code where I create the tabel:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_Name = "player_names";
public static final String KEY_Score = "player_score";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HighScore";
private static final String DATABASE_TABEL = "ScoreList";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper myHelper;
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Skapar tabellen
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABEL + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_Name + "  TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_Score + " TEXT NOT NULL); "                 
        );
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: please add also the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's complaining that you don't have the column "KEY_ROWID" in your table *ScoreList*

1. Show us the value that you've defined for the variable *KEY_ROWID*
2. Show us how you created the table *ScoreList*

Double check that the value you set for the KEY_ROWID const (it is a const variable, right?) matches the column name you used when you created the table.

Comment: Well, I do have a column named KEY_ROWID. So, I have no idea why it's complaining about that.

Comment: Very weird. For some reason it appears to be resolving the value of KEY_ROWID as "KEY_ROWID" instead of "_id". Try hard-coding the column names when performing your query and see if that works, then we can figure out a solution. (e.g. myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABEL, new String[] {"_id", "player_names",...).

Comment: Also, is the getData() method in the same class as the DBHelper? If not, is there a chance you have those constants (KEY_ROWID...) defined in multiple places?

Comment: I tried hard-coding it, still got the same problem. Yes, getData() is in the same class as DbHelper.

Comment: If you are using an emulator, pull the database and view it with some sort of SQLite database viewer. Maybe somehow the tables aren't being created properly and you'll be able to see the columns/data in the viewer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data

Comment: I tried my application on another eclipse, and now everything works fine. That's wierd, didn't change a thing. Thanks for the help anw!